# Run multiple commands using sudo over ssh

Tags: shell, sudo

I am using a Redhat 7.8 system and trying to run a similar command from a remote Jenkins scheduler.
The command is like:
`ssh userA@host sudo -u userB -- sh -c 'whoami; whoami'`
The output is

`userB`

`userA`

I am expecting the output as:

`userB`

`userB`

Not able to fix this. 
Tried sudo options like `-i`, `-s` and `-- sh -c`

The sudoer file has following config:

`userA    ALL=(userB) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the single quotes are removed as part of `ssh` constructing a single command to pass to the remote shell, so you are really running

```
sudo -u userB -- sh -c whoami; whoami
```

In general, you alway want to pass a single string argument to `ssh`, rather than let it combine multiple arguments into a single command.

```
ssh userA@host "sudo -u userB -- sh -c 'whoami; whoami'"
```